# Maven not compiling anotations

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a class which is annotated with:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.AccOpsProcessorWS")
```

Whenever I am running mvn clean install I am getting below error:

```
annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ws.AccOpsProcessorWS")
```

I am not able to understand the problem here. JDK version in eclipse and machine is 1.6

Comment: your maven `pom.xml` is not correct in the compiler plugin. this line is where that is self evident `annotations are not supported in -source 1.3` it says you have 1.3 configured

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear `use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations`. After version `5` is `1.6` :) Your `pom.xml` configuration is wrong.

Maven has different configuration for JDK version than eclipse, check if it is proper.

[Configure JDK version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) in `maven-compiler-plugin`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

[Annotations in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) are available from JDK 1.5

Comment: If I remove annotations everything works fine. What is issue with annotation?

Comment: Annotations was introduced in Java 1.5

Comment: That I know.My compiler is 1.6

Comment: Sir to make it more clear I am using some apis which are available from JDK 1.6 e.g BlockingQueue. There is no error on those only annotaion is problem.

Comment: OK, post your `pom.xml` or `maven-compiler-plugin` section. The message is clear to me: `use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations`. You are using this new APIs in Eclipse or maven?

Comment: <build>
    <finalName>maven-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

Comment: Use `mvn help:effective-pom` to show you what your effective pom (including all parent poms and the master pom) is. Note that the master pom depends on your installed Maven version, and I can remember versions where in the master POM maven-compiler-plugin was configured to target 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining what JDK to compile under?  For example:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```